# Sorting an array of objects based on the index after mapping through an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I am fetching an array of objects from the server and I use "map" to render the array elements as following :

```
data.map((item, index) => {
     <div>{item.index + 1}</div>
     <div>{item.name}</div>
     <div>{item.price}</div>
})
```

and I get a list of items starting from index 1 in ascending order. What I want to do is, I want to rearrange the array in a descending order instead. I want the first element rendered with the latest index that indicates the last element of the array. Is there a way to achieve this in javascript and ReactJs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post an example of the output you want versus the output you have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by issueing the `reverse` method:

```js
data.reverse().map((item, index) => {
     <div>{item.index + 1}</div>
     <div>{item.name}</div>
     <div>{item.price}</div>
})
```

Do keep in mind that this also changes the original array. So the `reverse` method will not only return a reversed array of `data`, but also mutate the `data` array itself.

Comment: _I want the first element rendered with the latest index that indicates the last element of the array_

Comment: Hmmm maybe I am misunderstanding the question. I will ask the OP to post an example of the output he wants.

Comment: That worked perfectly as expected. I just fixed the index to start from the length of the array. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
data.map((item, index) => {
     <div>{data.length - item.index}</div>
     <div>{item.name}</div>
     <div>{item.price}</div>
})
```

is the `item.index` intentional here? or did you mean just `index`?

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood is that you want to sort this in descending order of 'index' that is present as a key in every object. If that is the case, this will work.

```
data
  .sort((a,b)=>{return b.index-a.index}) // sorting it in descending order
  .map((item, index) => {
     <div>{item.index + 1}</div>
     <div>{item.name}</div>
     <div>{item.price}</div>
})
```